# Scraping Yahoo Finance for Dow Index in Python

Tags: python, indexing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the Dow Jones stock index from Yahoo Finance with Beautiful Soup in Python.

Here is what I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=^DJI"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup:
    date = row.find('span', 'time_rtq_ticker').text.strip()
    print date
```

Here is the element inspection from google chrome: 
[image]

How can I only scrape the 17,555.47 number from the span tags?

Comment: Are you wanting to learn how to scrape with BeautifulSoup, or are you just interested in the data?  If you want the data, I believe their [api](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs) may be a better source.

Comment: I just simply want to scrape this one number from Yahoo Finance. Cheers

Comment: Your call for "soup = BeautifulSoup(html)" may return an error given you don't declare the variable 'html'. Should it read 'myurl' instead of 'html' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `find`, very easy indeed, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

myurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=^DJI"
# I use requests to get the html content
html = requests.get(myurl).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# you don't need to iterate the children, just use find
# and you need to use attrs { key: value }, not just 'time_rtq_ticker'
soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'time_rtq_ticker'}).text
u'17,554.47'
```